# Single non-white-space characters in the C preprocessor

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

From the C11 Standard Draft N1570, §6.4/3:

> [...] The categories of preprocessing tokens are: header names, identifiers,
>   preprocessing numbers, character constants, string literals,
>   punctuators, and single non-white-space characters that do not
>   lexically match the other preprocessing token categories.<sup>69)</sup> **If a ' or
>   a " character matches the last category, the behavior is undefined.** [...]
>
> <sup>69)</sup> An additional category, placemarkers, is used internally in translation phase 4 (see 6.10.3.3); it cannot occur in source files.

<sub>(Emphasis mine.)</sub>

I cannot find a valid way to code a program containing a valid preprocessing token `"`.

Comment: The single non-white-space characters could be currency symbols such as $, £, ¢ or €, or either a back-quote or an at-sign.  Control characters other than those with _`\z`_ notation would also qualify.  The quotes have me puzzled pro tem.  The preprocessor tokenizes, and I don't see how it can have a quote that isn't either part of a character constant or part of a string literal.  My nearest guess is seeing `\'` or `\"` outside a string or character constant; but I'm far from convinced. The backslash is in the other category; the quote then stands on its own as part of a string or character.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler what about `#define A "` is that conform to the standard ?

Comment: It was downvoted because your question was very hard to understand. I only understood it because I searched a C11 draft for what you provided as a quote and replaced your quote with the full one. Next time, take your time adding enough information and formatting your question properly.

Comment: In that case it is fine. @Downvoter (nice username)

Comment: (about `#define a "`) That is the whole point. The preprocessor *basically* tokenizes based on whitespace, and recognises strings as single tokens. But unmatched quotes cannot be valid tokens. Maybe a similar exception is made for unmatched  `<` and `>` ? (Maybe this is not needed)

Comment: My expectation is that `#define A "` shouldn't work — that's an incomplete string literal.  And I'm not coming up with any other way of generating a quote out of the replacement text for a macro either.  But I may be lacking imagination and/or caffeine.  With GCC 6.3.0, even with no compilation warnings requested, `#define A "` generates: `warning: missing terminating " character`, so it appears to be one way a compiler might allow it, but it is syntactically invalid so other compilers could treat it differently.

Comment: @wildplasser: `<` and `>` are perfectly reasonable tokens (both during preprocessing and during processing). Perhaps you are thinking of their use in `#include` directives? In that case you could create a directive out of macros, although it might not work as expected since the details are implementation defined (section 6.10.2 para 4)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler When Per Bothner and Neil Booth and I rewrote GCC's preprocessor, back in 1999-2001, we made a design decision that as many instances of preprocessor-time UB as possible would be treated as promptly diagnosed compile errors.  I _think_ this particular instance of UB is meant to permit old preprocessors _not_ to diagnose `#define a "`.

Comment: @zwol: Thanks for the info.  I think you may well be right about the rule being originally a transition measure for old preprocessors (pre-standard ones).  The C90 standard has the wording too, so that's plausible.

Answer (score 2):

The text you highlighted says that if a <kbd>'</kbd> or <kbd>"</kbd> is used in such a way that it would be a single non-whitespace character preprocessing token, then the program is invalid (i.e. "the behaviour is undefined"). So no self-respecting compiler will allow you do do that; compilers certainly don't have any obligation to do anything you might consider sensible with explicitly undefined behaviour.

Comment: "Undefined behavior" usually means the Committee could not think of any reasonable behavior, and so they leave it to compiler writers. But I'm also at a loss seeing how a compiler could justify passing this silently by, as *valid* code. I bet it's a failsafe, though, because a single `'` may not be caught by a string-literal interpreter routine.